# Writing out an array using fprintf

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble writing an array of double numbers in a text file. The problem is, the code runs, but doesn't write out anything.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main() {

     FILE *out;
     double numbers[30];
     int i=0;

     for(i;i<30;i++) 
         scanf("%lf", &numbers[i]);

     out=fopen("out.txt", "w");

     if (out == NULL) {

         fprintf(stderr, "error in opening .txt");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     while ( i<30 ) {

         fprintf(out, "%.3f", numbers[i]);
         i++;
     }

     fclose(out);

     return 0;
 }
```

Basically, the code is supposed to write out an array of 30 double numbers in a text file, and round the decimals to '.3'.

Comment: Could you please add the tag 'C' ?

Comment: You forgot to set i back to zero after the first loop.

Comment: Yes add i = 0; in front of while( i < 30 )

Comment: Use a` for`  - Better than a while loop in this case. Reset `i`. Use braces around `scanf` and check the return value

Comment: Wow, um yes it worked, I'm embarassed.....

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to re-initialise `i` to 0, hence the current value of `i` is 30, which effectively causes the `while` loop to *not execute*.

```
 i = 0; //Re-initialise i.
 while ( i<30 ) {

         fprintf(out, "%.3f", numbers[i]);
         i++;
     }
```

It would be better, if you use a `for` loop, as it's syntax helps you to remember to initialise the increment variable.

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
     fprintf(out, "%.3f", numbers[i]);
```